# nginx redirect if other referer than my site

Tags: redirect, nginx, hotlinking

I have nginx webserver and people are starting to hotlink to download.php and that gives me nothing.

I wish to add 4 white list sites from which it is possible to hotlink (domains of my site) and make others that hotlink to my site get redirected from download.php?id=32 to details.php?id=32 so they coul press the download button there and then download the file.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Check the example of the [referer](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRefererModule) module.  Just use a rewrite instead of the return.